# MYSQL Selection more than one value

Tags: mysql, select, numbers

```
$query = $query."AND `category` != '(1,2)') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $a , $b" ;
```

Long story short, can't find the right syntax for the above (1,2) and i don't want to write over with another AND because there may apear more values in future.

Hope somebody can help me ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NOT IN` operator.

```
$query = $query."AND `category` NOT IN (1,2)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $a , $b" ;
```

Comment: Doens't give the desired result - for example my query looks now like this: SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE (`userid` = 2 AND `category` = '2') OR ( (`userid` = 1 AND `category` NOT IN '(1,2)') OR (`userid` = 9 AND `category` NOT IN '(1,2)') OR (`userid` = 10 AND `category` NOT IN '(1,2)') OR (`userid` = 4 AND `category` NOT IN '(1,2)') OR (`userid` = 8 AND `category` NOT IN '(1,2)') OR (`userid` = 7 AND `category` NOT IN '(1,2)') OR (`userid` = 3 AND `category` NOT IN '(1,2)') ) ORDER BY id

Comment: You need to remove quotes from braces.